# What is the error in the following python code snippet?

Tags: python-2.7, machine-learning

I was reading the the chapter on search engines in programming collective intelligence and came across the following code snippet and tried to implement it in IPython.However, I encountered error.Please Help.

```
def getmatchrows(self,q):
    fieldlist='w0.urlid'
    tablelist=''
    clauselist=''
    wordids=[]

    words=q.split()
    tablenumber=0

    for word in words:
        wordrow=self.con.execute("select rowid from wordlist where word='%s'" % word).fetchone()
        if wordrow!=None:
            wordid=wordrow[0]
            wordids.append(wordid)
            if tablenumber>0:
                tablelist+=','
                clauselist+=' and '
                clauselist+='w%d.urlid=w%d.urlid and '&(tablenumber-1,tablenumber)
            fieldlist+=',w%d.location'%tablenumber
            tablelist+='wordlocation w%d'%tablenumber
            clauselist+='w%d.wordid=%d'%(tablenumber,wordid)
            tablenumber+=1
    fullquery="select %s from %s where %s"%(fieldlist,tablelist,clauselist)
    cur=self.con.execute(fullquery)
    rows=[row for row in cur]
    return row,wordids
```

I got the following error:

```
e.getmatchrows('the')
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
OperationalError                          Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-65d6f760f6c8> in <module>()
----> 1 e.getmatchrows('the')

C:\Users\Blue\Anaconda\searchengine.py in getmatchrows(self, q)
    134                                 tablenumber+=1
    135                 fullquery="select %s from %s where %s"%(fieldlist,tablelist,clauselist)
--> 136                 cur=self.con.execute(fullquery)
    137                 rows=[row for row in cur]
    138                 return row,wordids

OperationalError: near "where": syntax error
```

Answer (score 0):

You have an SQL error.  Start by properly formatting your SQL.  [Here is a quick tutorial](http://zetcode.com/db/mysqlpython/).  And here is the syntax change I would make first.

```
fullquery="SELECT %s FROM %s WHERE %s"%(fieldlist,tablelist,clauselist)
```

In other words, consider using uppercase on your SQL keywords and rerun it.

Comment: nopes,its not still resolving the error.Still get the same error.

Comment: is it showing the same error? can you run the code in an editor?

Comment: 'e.getmatchrows('the')
OperationalError)
<ipython-input-5-65d6f760f6c8> in <module>()
 e.getmatchrows('the')

C:\Users\Blue\Anaconda\searchengine.pyc in getmatchrows(self, q)
    134                                 tablenumber+=1
    135                 fullquery="SELECT %s FROM %s WHERE %s"%(fieldlist,tablelist,clauselist)
 136                 cur=self.con.execute(fullquery)
    137                 rows=[row for row in cur]
    138                 return row,wordids
OperationalError: near "where": syntax error'